# как спрятать (не пускать за границы) span::after внутри того же span элемента

Tags: html, css

Как спрятать (не пускать за границы) span::after внутри того же span элемента?

Примечание: я знаю что можно добавить к `div` элементу свойство `overflow: hidden` и всё заработает, но мне нужно скрывать `::after` именно внутри того же элемента, а именно `span`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #222;
}

.custom-btn {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 10px;  
}

.custom-btn:hover span {
    border-color: rgb(73, 78, 155);
    color: #fff;
}

.custom-btn:hover span:first-child::after {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.custom-btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(62, 67, 134);
  border-radius: inherit;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.custom-btn span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  background-color: rgb(54, 59, 115);
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.2);
}
```

```html
  <div class="custom-btn">
    <span>btn</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам всего лишь нужно для `span` добавить `position: relative;`, тогда всё будет работать так, как Вам надо:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #222;
}

.custom-btn {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 10px;  
}

.custom-btn:hover span {
    border-color: rgb(73, 78, 155);
    color: #fff;
}

.custom-btn:hover span:first-child::after {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.custom-btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(62, 67, 134);
  border-radius: inherit;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.custom-btn span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  background-color: rgb(54, 59, 115);
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-btn">
    <span>btn</span>
  </div>
```

Почему так: `absolute` работает относительно родительского `position`, если родительский выставлен как `static` (т.е ничего не прописано), то элемент отрисуется относительно элемента более верхнего уровня с `relative` (или относительно `body`, если прицепиться будет не к чему). Именно поэтому у Вас `overflow:hidden` на `div` работает, потому что там уже есть `reative`.

Comment: Супер, спасибо!